# Cordova iOS: Load videos with downloaded html's and video files

Tags: ios, cordova, video, html5-video, inappbrowser

I have the following issue:

- I have an iOS Cordova Application.
- The application download a zip file and decompress it in "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/content/myfolder" by ussing the following Cordova plugins: org.apache.cordova.file-transfer, org.apache.cordova.file and https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/zip.git
- Inside the zip there is an "index.html" file with "video tags" on it.
- I was able to succesfully load and execute the "index.html" file, but the video doesn't load.

I know that the video file was decompressed successfully because:

- I check the file inside my iPad.
- I embed the video in the index of the cordova app (not the downloaded one) in the following way and it works:

  ```
   var videocontainer = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
   var videosource = document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0];
   var newmp4 = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + 'content/myfolder/videos/myvideo.mp4';
   videosource.setAttribute('src', newmp4);
   videocontainer.load();
   videocontainer.play();
  ```

But, the video is not loaded/played inside the downloaded HTML file. To understand what I'm doing, I have to develop an application that will be updated by downloading its contents from zips, and the contents includes pages with videos embeded on them. It works on PC and Android, but not in iOS.

I tried the following things:

- Loading the page in "_self". The page is displayed but not the video.
- Loading the page in an iframe. Same result.
- Loading the page within an inAppBrowser (plugin). Same result.
- Video tag with source src="videos/myvideo.mp4"  (works in Web and Android). Same result.
- Video tag with source src="./videos/myvideo.mp4" (works in Web and Android). Same result.
- Video tag with source src= cordova.file.documentsDirectory + 'content/myfolder/videos/myvideo.mp4' (with JS, by passing the path in a query string, same path that works in the root index.html as I described before). Same result.
- Video tag with source src= cordova.file.documentsDirectory + 'cdvfile://localhost/persistent/content/myfolder/videos/myvideo.mp4'. Same result.
- All the combination of previous things. Same result....

Loading the downloaded resources in a DIV is not an option, because the resources (images, css, javascripts, audios, videos, etc.) are downloaded on other iOS device's folder: the app's Documents' folder (cdvfile://localhost/persistent/).

I thing I tried almost everything... Why is not trivial to play a video tag, inside an html, that are both in the app's Documents' folder???

:-(

EDIT 1: Cordova Version = 3.6.3

Comment: Try to be a bit more precise with you questions. What system are you developing for? (Windows Phone, Blackberry, Android, iOS, ...)? What devices (tablets, phones)? Which Versions do you support (iOS 7.1+,...)? And if possible, please show an example for your index.html file that is inside the zipped file you download. And maybe a folder structure for your app to understand what you want to achieve ... thanks

Comment: AS I told in the beggining "I have an **iOS** Cordova Application." thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution Founded!!**

In almost all the android and iOS examples, downloaded content is being executed from **"cordova.file.documentsDirectory"**.

Then, when you link this content in a  or  (by using AJAX), everything works fine (CSS, images, links) but media tags ( and ).

Again, I dont know why, but almost all the examples downloads and unzip contents by using this path.

After several days being blocked with this issue (I found lots of forums where the devs have to modify all their projects by using plugins like Cordova Media, jaeger25 Html5Video, etc, etc), I tried by using the following path: **"cordova.file.dataDirectory"**

I download, unzip and execute the HTMLs from this path and **everything works** with no parsing/modifications to the HTML files (that in my case were thousands). **100% compability with  and  tags with relative sources' path in an IFRAME!!!!!!**

Comment: You get +1 for finding a solution on your own, and sharing it with us!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you code the video links into the index.html inside the zip you decompress on the device.

Those links need to get "updated" with some javascript parser, BEFORE you actually load or navigate to this page in your phonegap app.

If your example is caused in Android, you definetly need to include the HTML5 Video plugin here:

https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video

On iOS the  tag will work for local files. But the links need to be absolute.

And the links will change if you recompile your app or reinstall it.
The files will be available, but the APP ID will have changed and the absolute path also.

Example of an iOS path:

```
/var/mobile/Applications/<application UUID>/Documents/path/to/file
```

Hope you solved your problem.

Comment: To "update" the HTMLs is not an option. The downloaded content displays videos in several ways (by the video tag embeded and/or inserted by JQuery, etc). Each ZIP has "micro-html5-application" with dozens of HTMLs, and videos with particular CSSs styles, some of them autoplays, some of the has interactive content in synchro with the video, etc.

Comment: Use a plugin was not an option, for the same "user experience" requirements.